# How can we learn the values of the parameters for Levenshtein distance?

Tags: self-study, text-mining, unsupervised-learning, hyperparameter

I am trying to filter out similar-looking names from a database. Once I have figured out the names, I will merge them into a single entity. To achieve this, I am planning on using edit-distance methods such as Levenshtein. However, the problem with these methods is that they have parameters whose values need to set according to our requirement.

I don't have any prior information about the dataset and I am planning to use grid search to find the value of these parameters.

Is this a good idea to follow? One thing that I would like to state is that this is going to be an unsupervised learning which means that I might have to manually check several data points to decide if my model is over-fitting or under-fitting.